# Check if Google Places API is enabled programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am writing a web app that uses [Google's autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete). Now, I will be given an API key, but will not know if it has the Places API enabled. I need a way to check if the Places API is enabled in the key's project. In particular, I want to keep from spamming the console with the "This API project is not authorized to use this API" errors. The autocomplete is implemented as follows:

`new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('input.location-address')[0]);`

This works with the Places API enabled, but I need a way to check that that is enabled. Something like:

`function keyHasPlacesEnabled(api_key, callback) { ... }`

If the Places API is disabled the console gets spammed with these errors:

```
This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_ For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank You ~ Ethan

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to do it like the [Google Places API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) does, with a callback

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>`

If you want to hide errors from your console, put the inside a `try`/`catch` block where the `catch` sets `initMap` to `null`.

Comment: But how does this help to know if the Maps API key I have been given also has the places api enabled?

Comment: I saw your comment. That still wouldn't help me. I am loading the api fine, and I am able to make calls. The Google Maps Javascript API will console log errors when I try to use the autocomplete api without enabling it. I wanted to stop these errors. So, I resorted to adding a site setting that will tell me if the api key has the autocomplete api enabled. Thank you anyway